# 2 BufferedReaders from one InputStream

Tags: java, url

I made the following code:

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("http://bbc.com");
  is = url.openStream();
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
  System.out.println(in.readLine());
  //in.close(); with this next lines throw java.io.IOException: stream is closed
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-2"));
  System.out.println(in.readLine().length());
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is the second BufferedReader starts read from a few different point after almost every program run (the printed length is different). Same problems occur withe the same encoding. How can I read encoding and then read content with this encoding without creating new InputStream (every creation of new InputStream takes 0.1 to 3 s depending on site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you copy the entire stream, e.g. by repeatedly calling `read()` and then writing the results into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You can then get a byte array from that, and create multiple independent `ByteArrayInputStream` wrappers around the byte array.

(You can use Guava's `ByteStreams.ToByteArray(is)` as an alternative for the first part.)

Another alternative would be to wrap the original `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`, call `mark` immediately with a "large enough" limit, then reset it after you've read the first line, before creating the second `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a BufferedReader to read the first line, I would just read characters until I find a '\n'.

Comment: When i change in.readLine() to (char)in.read() in my code only, the second printed char is different almost every program run too.

Comment: Absolutely, so long as you know that the first line will be of reasonable length. Without that guarantee, you should do the buffering for the first line manually.

Comment: @Andrej yes, the issue is that the BufferedReader will try to fill its buffer (event when read() is called). That's why you shouldn't use it.